# Delphi / ADO : Which components? TADODataSet and TADOCommand or TADOQuery?

Tags: delphi, ado

According to http://www.delphigroups.info/2/3/181838.html <sup>*([archive](https://archive.vn/we0HD))*</sup>

> The preferred approach with ADO
> components is to use TADODataSet and
> TADOCommand. TADOQuery (and TADOTable
> and TADOStoredProc) are provided for
> compatibility.
>
> Use TADODataSet for SQL that returns
> result-sets and TADOCommand for SQL
> that does not.

I am a clueless beginner, who is about to code a lot of ADO stuff. Is the above statement correct?

---

p.s. Is there any good open source Windows program that will let me visualize & explore the contents of my databases?

Which components should I use for something which does/does not return a result?

Comment: I believe that the linked reference and your own question already provides the clues to answer you. Use TADOCommand and TADODataSet. Additionally, use DB Aware controls for the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That statement is correct. TADODataset and TADOCommand are direct interfaces to the native ADO objects, and can perform all the task made by the other three, which exist to ease porting application written for the BDE (Borland Database Engine), implmenting a similar interface - they end up calling the first two.

Comment: Can you help?  When I use TADODataset.Execute();  I end up with a _Recordset   can you tell me how to loop over this to see the results?

Comment: If you use TADODataset to execute a SELECT, simply open it (or set Active to True). Now you can use the First/Last/Next/Prev methods to iterate the result. It you use a TADOCommand, Execute returns an ADO interface, it has MoveXXXX methods to iterate over the resultset, check the ADO documentation.

Answer (score 4):

And I will go the half-oppositie! ;-)

There might be some cases when TADOQuery fits nicely for **both** of the jobs.
If your query will result in data use `TADOQuery.Acvite := True`,
If you need to perform update\insert\delete use `TADOQuery.ExecSQL.`

For example, you could write a query to UPDATE\ INSERT and SELECT a record and do it in one component instead of introducing two.

```
DECLARE @ID int, @Mode int, @SomeValue varchar(20)

SET @ID = :ID
SET @Mode = :Mode
SET @SomeValue = :SomeValue 

IF (@Mode = 1) //INSERT
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ID, SomeColumn) VALUES(@ID, @SomeValue)
END ELSE
IF (@Mode = 2) //UPDATE
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET SomeValue = @SomeValue WHERE ID = @ID
END ELSE
IF (@Mode = 3) //DELETE
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = @ID
END ELSE
IF (@Mode = 4) //SELECT
BEGIN
  IF (@ID = -1) //SELECT ALL
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable
  END ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE ID = @ID
  END
END
```

Just an example, written now. I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Which database do you use.
SqlBuddy is open source IDE to explore database.

Comment: +1  Thanks, that looks good (when I figure out how to run it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have **2 different classifications** here either depending on the **nature of the SQL object (TADOTable, TADOQuery and TADOStoredProc)** or the **action/result (TADODataSet and TADOCommand)**.
The historical Delphi approach is more of the 1st while ADO is by nature more of the 2nd.

Both can be useful depending on what you want to do.

I recommand you **read the Delphi help** on the ADO components.
For instance you'll find useful notes like: 
"ADOdb.TADODataSet and SQLExpr.TSQLDataSet have a CommandType property that lets you specify whether they represent a table, query, or stored procedure. Property and method names are most similar to query-type datasets, although TADODataSet lets you specify an index like a table type dataset."

If you are sure to **stick with ADO** and never need to change and port to other Data Layers, then **go the "ADO route" with TADODataSet and TADOCommand**.
You'll get the most of ADO with it and it will be easier to use MS docs and examples.

Comment: I'm such a n00b that I found the Delphi help confusing :-/  I suppose that it is genrally always that way when alternatives are offered, so I thought that I would ask the gurus.

  I woudl imagine that my command type will always be text.

Comment: If you use any version after Delphi 7 the help can confuse the most proficient Delphi developer.

Comment: I guess it's a trade off. You choose the easier, older, compatible (ie not ADO specific) paradigm with TADOQuery/TADOStoredProc or the more "native" ADO way. Although you can, try not to mix them.

Comment: `If you use any version after Delphi 7 the help can confuse the most proficient Delphi developer.` Very true words......

Answer (score 2):

### SELECT statements

For issuing DQL statements that return a data set (e.g. SELECT)

- **TADOQuery**

  ```
  qry.Sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  qry.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  qry.Open;
  ```
- **TADODataSet**

  ```
  ds.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  ds.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  ds.Open;
  ```
- **TADOCommand**

  ```
  cmd.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  rs: _Recordset;
  rs := cmd.Execute;
  ```

  The ADOCommand will return a native ADO IRecordset. You can use the `Recordset` interface directly (it's not that hard), or you can wrap it in a friendly Delphi wrapper class:

  ```
  ds.Recordset := rs;
  ```

  or

  ```
  qry.Recordset := rs;
  ```

### INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements

For issuing DML statements that do not return a data set (e.g. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

- **TADOQuery**

  ```
  qry.Sql.Text := 'DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  qry.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  qry.ExecuteOptions := [eoExecuteNoRecords];
  qry.ExecSql;
  ```
- **TADOCommand**

  ```
  cmd.CommandText := 'DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  cmd.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  cmd.ExecuteOptions := [eoExecuteNoRecords];
  cmd.Execute;
  ```
- **TADODataSet**: Cannot be done. TADODataSet will throw an exception if no dataset is returned by the statement

  ```
  ds.CommandText := 'DELETE FROM Users WHERE Name = :username';
  ds.Parameters.ParamByName('username').Value := 'ian';
  ds.ExecuteOptions := [eoExecuteNoRecords];
  ds.Open; // <-- Exception: "CommandText does not return a result set"
  ```

### Chart form

```
| Component   | Issue command | Return rows |
|-------------|---------------|-------------| 
| TADODataSet |  No           |  Yes        |
| TADOCommand |  Yes          |  Yes¹       |
| TADOQuery   |  Yes          |  Yes        |

¹ Recordset interface
```

### Inheritance hierarchy

- TComponent

  - TADOCommand *(near native ADO access)*
  - TDataSet  *(Delphi's base data set model)*

    - **TCustomADODataSet**  *(exposing ADO as DataSet)*

      - **TADODataSet** *(cannot issue DML)*
      - **TADOQuery** *(can issue DML and DQL)*
    - *TCustomClientDataSet* *(exposing in-memory tables as a DataSet)*
    - *TBDEDataSet* *(exposing BDE as DataSet)*
    - *TCustomSQLDataSet* *(exposing dbExpress as DataSet)*

**TADOCommand** is the closest to the metal for issuing raw queries.

**TADODataSet** and **TADOQuery** use Delphi's existing database object model to expose ADO data sources

**TADODataSet** can only be used to represent data sets

**TADOQuery** is the jack-of-all-trades that can do everything.